# ObjectInputStream invalid stream header

Tags: java

When I'm using this shipet:

```
InputStream fs=new FileInputStream("some_file.txt");
ObjectInputStream is=new ObjectInputStream(fs);
```

the Java shows error:

```
>java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3130300A
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
```

`FileInputStream` works fine. `DataInputStream` works too.
The code runs in main method, and there are not any another code. I used another file, for example pom.xml, the error remained the same.

I can use `DataInputStream` instead of `ObjectInputStream`, but I don't understand the cause of such behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read a text file with an ObjectInputStream. You can only write data created with an ObjectOutputStream, or some other device that follows the same format protocol.